# Snipe-IT on IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

Is it possible to install snipe-it application using php 8.0? Everything I see says php 7.4 but I want to use 8.0 and am getting a 500 internal server error on my Windows 2019 server VM. Is there something I am missing or need to added in order to get the installation working correctly?

It appears I keep getting different 500 errors via web browser.

Comment: If the vendor/developers are good enough at Windows/IIS, they should have warned you that PHP 8.x on Windows/IIS should be avoided, https://docs.phpmanager.xyz/getting-started/supported-platforms.html#php-on-windows-status

Comment: As suggest by Lex Li. PHP 8 or later are not supported on the Windows and IIS. It is not recommended to host your PHP apps on the IIS. Thanks for your understanding.